# My shopify store gives 404 error when sharing on a social media site like facebook

Tags: dns, shopify

I have a Shopify store and have pointed my domain to it: https://selectivestore.in/

I am having two issues with it:

1. When I share any URL from the site on Facebook or Instagram, it shows a 404 error. I have checked in the Facebook sharing debugger and tried deleting the cache, but nothing solved this; however, the website loads perfectly fine in the browser.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fselectivestore.in%2Fproducts%2Frecharge...

2. Sometimes it shows a 404 error in the browser, and after doing it 4-5 times, the page refreshes, and then it loads the website. It also shows the domain registrar's default page sometimes, so I think there is some issue with the DNS.

I have both A and CNAME records pointed to Shopify in the DNS:

- An A Record that points to: 23.227.38.65
- A CNAME that points to: shops.shopify.com

I have also made sure that there are no AAAA records in the DNS, but that also did not solve the issue.

> > The DNS records were updated two days before, so I waited long enough to get this fixed, but it is still the same issue.

> > I have also searched StackOverflow and no similar forum solves my issue.

I have read this somewhere and maybe this is the reason that to some of my customers, the website does not load, and also to me sometimes on mobile networks, I don't know if this makes sense:

"Some of my customers that have mobile networks who only allow for IPV6, cannot access my Shopify website as it only has an IPV4 address. I thought it would be possible to enable a feature that will merely mirror my website onto a pseudo-IPV6, so they can access my website."

Let me know please if someone knows the solution. Thanks in advance.